# Assign sequential count for numerical runs

Tags: arrays, matlab, sequences

I'd like to assign a cumulative numerical value for sequential runs in a binary vector. What I have is

```
x = [0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0],
```

and what I would like is

```
y = [1 2 3 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6].
```

The solution using sum/cumsum/unique/find range of functions alludes me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
a = arrayfun(@(x)(1:x), diff(find([1,diff(x),1])), 'uni', 0);
[a{:}]
```

The idea is to generate a list of the 'run lengths', i.e. `[3,2,1,3,1,1,6]` in your case, then just concatenate a bunch of vectors that count to each value in that list, i.e. `cat(2, 1:3, 1:2, 1:1, 1:3...`. I use `arrayfun` as a shortcut for reapplying the `:` operator and then use the comma separated list that `{:}` returns as a shortcut for the concatenation.

Comment: Well spotted on applying ``@(x) 1:x`` on runlength encoding!

Comment: wow. great! Your one liners are so cool (and complex) sometimes they give me a headache! Nice job.

Comment: Though (at least for me personally) ``a = arrayfun(@(x) (1:x), diff(find([true, diff(x) ~= 0, true])), 'uni', 0)`` would be slightly more readable.

Comment: @Nras agreed - but I think Bentoy's answer is better anyways

Comment: @Dan - nice solution. I wouldn't have considered using arrayfun. Thank you.

Comment: @J..S Thanks but I think you should consider the `diff`/`cumsum` approach. I don't know what your goals are and I haven't benched marked but I would suspect that it is faster and in my opinion it is clearer as well

Comment: I've borrowed this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27948340/2586922) (with due credit)

Answer (score 6):

(Not a one-liner, alas ...):

```
F = find(diff(x))+1;
y = ones(size(x));
y(F) = y(F)-diff([1,F]);
y = cumsum(y);
```

First, find all positions in `x` where there is a change; then build a vector of 1 where you substract the length of each continuous segment. At the end, take the cumsum of it.

Comment: This is a clever approach!

Comment: I also had the usual suspects ``find``, ``diff`` and especially ``cumsum`` in my mind when reading the question. This would look pretty similar to my (yet non-existent) approach.

Comment: This is the type of solution I originally had in mind - but couldn't quite get working. Many thanks @Bentoy13.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix such that each run is on a different column, and then do the cumulative sum:

```
t = sparse(1:numel(x), cumsum([1 diff(x)~=0]), 1);
y = nonzeros(cumsum(t).*t).';
```

---

Use [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with a custom function to generate each increasing pattern in a different cell, and then concatenate all cells:

```
y = accumarray(cumsum([1 diff(x)~=0]).', 1, [], @(x) {1:numel(x).'});
y = [y{:}];
```

Comment: an alternative solution I would have never considered.